# Is there a way to hide the inner faces of cubes in Ursina?

Tags: python, game-development, ursina

I am currently struggling to find a way to hide the inner faces of a chunk of a 32x32x4 block (4096 blocks) using the cube entity of Ursina. Would anyone have an idea of how to hide faces we don't see? Here we can see the whole chunk and my FPS is dying even though I have a RTX 3060

[image: Here we can see the whole chunk and my fps dying even tho i have a RTX 3060]

I tried using a Cube mesh, using `Mesh()`, adding vertices to it, and triangles. The problem is, I couldn't find a way to make textures show up on each face properly

I used this video as a reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPaCPk4n2rE&t=774s&ab_channel=windsurftweeds

This is the result:

[image: This is a Entity with the blockMesh model]

Here's the code I used for the mesh

```
import ursina
from ursina import *

blockMesh = Mesh(
    vertices=[
        [0,0,0], # 0
        [1,0,0], # 1
        [1,0,1], # 2
        [0,0,1], # 3
        [0,1,0], # 4
        [1,1,0], # 5
        [1,1,1], # 6
        [0,1,1], # 7
    ],
    triangles=[
        [3, 2, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 5, 4],
        [1, 2, 6, 5],
        [2, 3, 7, 6],
        [3, 0, 4, 7],
        [4, 5, 6, 7],
    ],
    normals=[
        [-1,-1,-1], # 0
        [1,-1,-1], # 1
        [1,-1,1], # 2
        [-1,-1,1], # 3
        [-1,1,-1], # 4
        [1,1,-1], # 5
        [1,1,1], # 6
        [-1,1,1], # 7
    ],
    uvs=[
        [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0],
        [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0],
    ]
)

blockMesh.generate()



class Voxel(Entity):
    def __init__(self, block, position=(0, 0, 0)):
        super().__init__()
        self.model     = blockMesh
        self.texture   = "doge_grass.png"
        
Voxel("Test")
```